# Yearly population growth rate throughout history

Tags: demography, world

Has there been a comprehensive analysis of relative human population growth rate throughout history?

I'm interested in seeing how the growth rate (not world population) has evolved in the past several thousand years. A graph would be ideal for this but all I've been able to find is relative growth for the last several hundred years. All the graphs I've found that deals with population growth across centuries only display absolute numbers. As growth is exponential I can't really draw any conclusions about growth relative to population.

What I'm looking for: a graph outlining estimated population growth rate per annum/decade/half-century, ideally since recorded history.

Comment: What is definition of "earliest human history"?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for, why existing data is insufficient or **what research you have already done**

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace Google only shows me absolute figures, not relative growth on a long scale. I've tried to narrow my search but this just leaves me with relatively recent census data or studies of (geographically/temporally) limited scope. I've attempted to clarify my question but welcome any feedback if it still doesn't fit the site format.

Comment: Is not relative growth calculated from absolute figures?

Comment: Please read the help. Do not post trivial questions. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Population_growth

Comment: @TylerDurden Please explain where that wikipedia article mentions relative population growth over more than a hundred years. If I could have found this information in a 5 minute search I wouldn't have needed to ask this question.

Comment: I think this is a good question. The wikipedia article does not address the change in growth rate over a period of millennia.

Comment: Population estimation is a matter of demography

Answer (score 6):

[image: historical growth rate Kremer]

Source: Kremer, Michael. "Population growth and technological change: one million BC to 1990." The Quarterly Journal of Economics (1993): 681-716.

Graph by Richard Vermillion.

Comment: +1 and it is obvious, there shall be a 0% growth again, it is interesting to see the point where colonization started in a bigger scale, and the industrial revolution. Nowadays we simply closing to the support limit of the Earth

Comment: The cited article quotes estimates by Deevey (1960), Durand (1977), McEvedy & Jones (1978). Has nobody been working on re-assessing/re-validating these data since then?

Comment: Durand (1977) quotes data from Colin Clark's 1968 book (Population Growth and Land Use, NY, St.Martin's Press). Deevey (1960) gets his data from Woytinskys' World Population and Production: Trends and Outlook (1953). McEvedy goes back to Clark and Durand. Are we relying on a single source here?